# Error reading variables: Cannot access memory at adress x

Tags: c++, memory-management

so probably a silly question but i'm not very familiar with C++ so...
Then i run this code, it crash with no error code after hitting the second if in the main

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "day.cpp"
#include "appointement.cpp"

using namespace std;
// Flags are placed as constants to easy access
const string mod="mod", lst="lst", rmv="rmv";
const string add="add", title="-t", date="-d";
bool ispresent (string command, string flag)
{
    int pos=command.find(flag);
    if (pos==-1)
    { 
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    string command;
    cout << "Hi, send command:";
   //this is analysed and searched for flags
    cin >> command;
    //if the "add" is present, create a new event (userEvent)
    if (ispresent (command, add))
    {
        cout << "add triggered";
        ofstream saveFile;
        saveFile.open("/tmp/.calendar/saveFile.txt");
        appointement userEvent; 
        // this test always fail
        if (ispresent(command, title))
        {      
            //search for "-t" to add the title to the event      
            cout << "-t triggered";
            int flag=command.find("-t")+2;
            cout << "placed after -t";
            userEvent.setTitle(command.substr(flag,command.find(" ")));
            cout << "title set";
            // search for "-d" to add the date to the event
            if (command.substr(flag,flag)==date)
            {
                int flag=flag+2;
                userEvent.setTimeNotification(command.substr(flag+2, command.find (" ")));
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

at first i thought at a bad test, but running it into gdb given me this error :

```
   ispresent (command=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x6a9b6f7a416ff400>,
   flag=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x3>) at main.cpp:13
```

I understand that there is something going with access right to the variables but i don't understand what is actually going on...
I check for similar questions here, but nobody seems to explain that is actually going on and how to fix/avoid it in the future

Comment: `command` will never contain whitespace.

Comment: Do *NOT* include cpp files!

Comment: In the line `int flag = flag + 2;` you are declaring a second variable called `flag`, hiding the first one. Didn't you get a compiler warning for it?

Comment: @molbdnilo the command i type for testing as whitespace (something like this: "add -t this")
no compiler warning, changed the name of the second one (so no more matching name in variables) and same issue

Comment: @Flxibit Print `command` immediately after you've read it and you will see that it only contains the first word. Then go read about how formatted extraction –  `>>` – works, and then read about `std::getline`.

Comment: The <error reading variable> is *probably* just a debugger problem, not a problem in the actual code. C++ debuggers aren't very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after @molbdnilo pointed out, my "command" isn't actually the way it thought it was and only contain the first string in the command (each white space breaks my command in multiples strings).
So the issue is then i call the second test, it cannot work because my "command" variable is smaller than the position i tried to test, so then the program call the memory space where the continuation of the variable should be i get an memory error since this program is not allowed to use this memory space.